# PNG with Transparent Background Turns Black in ImageSource

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Edit: my issue was that in using SkiaSharp to scale down the image size I was encoding it as Jpeg instead of PNG. Encoding as PNG made the background transparent.

---

I am loading images from an HTTP endpoint, storing the image in a DB, and displaying the image in an ImageSource. I have a PNG with a transparent background. When the image is displayed the background turns black. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

- Is what I'm doing even possible? Download a PNG from HTTP with a transparent background, save PNG as byte[] in a database, and displaying the image in a `ContentPage` with the transparent background?
- Should I abandon DB storage for this image and save it on the filesytem?

---

Download Image as `ByteArray` and Convert to `ImageSource`

```cs
public ImageSource Image { get; set;} // NotifyPropertyChange is implemented

...

// download image
var client = new HttpClient();
var imageByteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

// convert ByteArray to ImageSource
Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageByteArray));
```

XAML `ImageSource`

```xml
<Image x:Name="image"
       Source="{Binding Image}" />
```

Sqlite DB Model Property & Conversion from ByteArray to ImageSource

```cs
public byte[] ImageByteArray { get; set; }

...

// convert ByteArray to ImageSource in Model
Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ImageByteArray));
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your approach, although I don't think storing images in the db is a great idea.   Have you tried testing with an HttpImageSource, or just including one of the images locally in the project?

Comment: The most likely problem is the image data itself. IIRC, for best portability cross-platform, use 32-bit format. Test as an embedded resource and/or as a file included in the project, to see if that works.

Comment: @Jason how would you recommend storing the file? Including the image locally in the project and settings the image source to the HTTP URL works; so the issue is with my storage.

Comment: When saving the file to the device the image loads with a transparent background. It looks like my best course of action is to save the image to the filesystem and store the location of the file in the database binding the image source to the file path. Is this bad practice?

Comment: In the file system.  I’m a little surprised that made a difference in the transparency

Comment: @Jason Thank you. An issue I have ran into is updating the image source does not update the image in the view. I'm using the MVVM baked into Xamarin.Forms. Have you seen this before? The image source is 1.png, click a button to change the source to 2.png and the Image still shows 1.png.

Comment: you may need to use Essentials.MainThread to be sure that the update is happening on the UI thread

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that I am using SkiaSharp to scale the image to a smaller size and I encoding in Jpeg format. Changing the encode to PNG fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question-asker states in a comment that the actual problem was that they used SkiaSharp to scale the image to a smaller size. At that step, they encoded the resulting image in JPEG - so it no longer had transparency.

"Changing the encode to PNG fixed my issue."

---

As an aside, if transparency isn't there, its important to examine the process in every step from image creation to storing on server to transmitting to client to final display. Examine output of each step, to be sure it is still .png format, and has transparency. (E.g. take the bytes, store them in a file, manually view that file in an image viewer that shows transparent areas.)